# iPhone SDK, how to make a button respond to a double click?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, double-click

In my iphone app, I've got buttons and I should make them respond to a double click.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use UIGestures

In the initWithFrame (or initWithCoder if you're using Interface Builder)

```
   UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];

    [doubleTap release];
    [singleTap release];
```

Then add the methods

```
- (void) doubleTap: (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender
{

     do whatever
}

- (void) singleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use gestures, Try this -

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [doubleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [yourView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [doubleTap release];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding following to button defination :-

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttontappedtwice)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
```

where buttontappedtwice is a method which will be called when u tap this particular button twice... Cheers

Comment: And read here for some useful implementation detail in your selector method - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109582/double-touch-on-uibutton.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
     if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
     }
}
```