# Doble Click Button event in xcode

Tags: objective-c, events, click

I want to open a web browser i.e Google page on clicking a button.
I am successfully getting this done on single click. But the same thing i want to achieve on double click of event.
I searched a lot about this and got a program that opens on clicking anywhere on the  screen.
please guide me if anyone has any kinda knowledge about this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109582/double-touch-on-uibutton

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

Suppose click is the action which gets called on :-

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(click) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

What you have to do is:-

Make a `BOOL` global variable

in `.h file` do:-

```
BOOL isDoubleClick;
NSTimer *doubleClickTimer;

in .m file do:-

-(IBAction)click
{
    if (isDoubleClick==YES) {
        //DOUBLE CLICK
        isDoubleClick=NO;
    }
    else if(isDoubleClick==NO)
    {
        //SINGLE CLICK
        isDoubleClick=YES;
        doubleClickTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(TimerReload:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }
    NSLog(@"bool %s", isDoubleClick ? "true" : "false");

}

-(void)TimerReload:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    doubleClickTimer = nil;
    isDoubleClick = NO;
}
```

Explanation:-

First your `isDoubleClick` is `NO`.When you clicks on the button for the first time it gets `YES`.After that again you clicks on the second time if it gets `YES` Then it means it is a double click and do whatever you want to perform on double click.Make `isDoubleClick` to `NO` so that next time click is treated as single click.

Use of Timer:-

For double click you need to ensure that two time click is done one after another.For that enable a timer on single click and after 2 second fire a timer method to set `isDoubleClick` to `NO` to ensure that now if user clicks on the button , the click will be treated as single not double.

I hope it will save your couple of hours.

Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

try to use this for the event

UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat