# 'Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'anyObject." - Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, set, nsobject

I'm checking to see if an element has been selected.

```
func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    // First, see if the game is in a paused state
    if !gamePaused
    {
        // Declare the touched symbol and its location on the screen
        let touch = touches.anyObject! as? UITouch
        let location = touch.locationInNode(symbolsLayer)
```

And this had previously compiled fine in Xcode 6.2 but with a 6.3 update, the line "let touch = touches.anyObject! as? UITouch" is throwing the error:

'Set' does not have a member named 'anyObject'

I've read through many similar question, but I can't seem to wrap my head around "To use the value, you need to “unwrap” it first." Especially because the answers seem to focus on notifications.

Thank you so much.
W

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771896/overriding-method-with-selector-touchesbeganwithevent-has-incompatible-type ?

Comment: Thanks Martin R. I have tried that but it appears to not quite be what is the issue, changing to what you suggested "override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if let touch = touches.first as? UITouch {" returns the error 'Set<NSObject> does not have a member named 'first". That's why it appeared it has something to do with classifying as an array?

Comment: Strange, the code compiles in my Xcode 6.3 project.

Comment: I am too much of a beginner to understand why that could be the case. Any coding I do is riddled with errors. Thank you so much for trying.

Answer (score 21):

```
let touch =  touches.first as? UITouch
```

`.first` can allow you to access first object of UITouch.

Since Xcode 6.3 uses an updated version of Swift (1.2) you need to convert your old code into Swift 1.2 (Edit -> convert -> To lastest Swift).

Swift 1.2, uses `Set`’s (new in Swift) instead of using `NSSet`’s (old one in Objective-C). Thus the touchbegan function also changes its parameters from NSSet to Set.

For more info, [refer this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent)

Comment: Please explain by adding some more code or reference links to improve the answer.

Comment: This is the reference https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/touchesBegan:withEvent:

Comment: Thanks. Can you edit your answer and add the same? and explain more, so everyone understands. SO is not meant to share links ONLY, but explain and give a reference link

Answer (score 3):

This would check for multiple touches in symbolsLayer

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    // First, see if the game is in a paused state
    if !gamePaused
    {
        // Declare the touched symbol and its location on the screen
        for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = (touch as! UITouch).locationInNode(symbolsLayer)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to have solved it! Thank you so much Martin!